# Problem in removing localhost name for deploying Next.js

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, next.js

I am working on an important next.Js project. And I am stuck while trying to change some api's.

For example:

```
import axios from "axios";

export const fetchCategories = async (id = false) => {
  try {
    if (id === false) {
      let response = await axios({
        method: "get",
        url: `http://localhost:3000/api/category/create`,
        json: true,
      });
      return response;
    }
```

This function is a component that makes an axios request to the next.js own server localhost, is there a way to change this url to get the actual dynamic route instead of a hardcoded one like this? I know there's a way I'm just struggling with this problem.

Comment: why are you hard coding the `http://localhost:3000` part? If you don't include that axios will automatically determine the domain and port from the browser/window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make a document with

```
export const NEXT_URL =
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FRONTEND_URL || "http://localhost:3000";
```

and then when you deploy set up an environment variable called NEXT_PUBLIC_FRONTEND_URL and set that to the URL of your nextjs website on Vercel. Then in the pages when you need the URL you can import it as `import {NEXT_URL} from "file location"`, then when your app is deployed it will look for this environment variable before defaulting to http://localhost:3000.

Here is my project where I have implemented this: [LINK](https://github.com/Thomas13702/DJ_Events_Frontend)

You can see in config/index.js is where this is, and then in my context/authcontext.js is where I predominately use it.

Comment: I will try it out. Thanks for the fast answer

Comment: It's not working on production vercel. It said about leaking environment variables.